# dc.js / d3.js - load json - data type is null

Tags: php, d3.js, dc.js

We have a dc.js page that loads json data via a php page. It has worked fine in development and on our own servers, however now we have uploaded it to an external server (Yahoo small business) it doesn't work we are getting a TypeError: data is null error in the console.

If we use a static JSON file (rather than getting the json via a php page using json_encode) it works.

I have been reading into CORS but I'm unsure whether this is the cause and also if there is any work around? The data is dynamic so via the php page was the way we wanted to go.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you tried to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ` to your PHP that return the JSON?

If it still fails, try using JSONP maybe?

Comment: Some recomendations: 1) Make sure your PHP its working fine on new server, put this at the very first line: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); [some servers die silent] 2) Call to PHP from browser, like: http://yoursite.com/yourphp.php?var1=value1 and it must return the JSON. 3) add type: "POST" to your ajax if your sending data. 4) console.log(yourReturnedData) to see what you get from server

Comment: I have added the header to the PHP page but that hasn't fixed it. The PHP page itself is returning the correct JSON, if I copy and paste that result into a file and call that file, it works. The error returned from Firefox is SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON. This still works on a local server.

Comment: @zeachco - If I change  `d3.json("data.php", function (error, data)` to `d3.xhr("data.php", function (error, data)` I do get data back, however I am then getting TypeError: data.forEach is not a function error. Any ideas?

Comment: At least you have a javascript error, inspect you data object to see if it's an array (supporting .forEach) or just an object / error message. If your JSON return an object like `{list: [1,2,3]}` you cannot do a `forEach` on it, but you might do it on some attribute of the returned object. If your response looks more like an error, please parse that error.

Comment: @NorthSide also forgot to mention that forEach is not supported on older browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach